# Unable to open file using FileProvider

Tags: android, file, android-studio, android-fileprovider, android-storage

I wish to open a file from downloads folder (/storage/emulated/0/Download) and this is my code
I first check if the file exists

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download" + File.separator + <file-name> + ".pdf");
                if(file.exists()) {
                    openfile("/storage/emulated/0/Download" + File.separator + <file-name> + ".pdf");
                    Log.d("upload", "onClick: already exists");
                }
                else {
                    downloadfile(Url);
                    Log.d("upload", "onClick: download");
                }
```

If the file exists I use this code to open the file

```
public void openfile(String path){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider",new File(path));
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose an application"));
}
```

This is my manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/path"/>
    </provider>
```

and my path.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

When I click to open the file it shows intent chooser and when drive pdf viewer is selected it opens up with a blank screen and closes immediately and when any other app is chosen then it shows error File not found(content://(package-name).provider/storage%2Femulated%2F0/Download/file-name.pdf). I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `If t the file exists...` Use File:exists() to determine if a file exists.

Comment: `new File(path)` You should show in your code the used value for `path`.

Comment: `name="storage/emulated/0"` Use a name without slashes.

Comment: @blackapps I have made the changes you have mentioned but the result is still the same and as for path it is mentioned where the function is being called

Comment: You should use Intent.EXTRA_STREAM for your uri.

Comment: @blackapps I am fairly new to android can you please help me out as to where and how I have to use it and what it does?

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: @blackapps included Intent.EXTRA_STREAM for the uri, still same result

Comment: I dont see that in your code

Answer (score 0):

maybe not

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
```

but

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
```

?